# Is the expected value independent of the number of repetitions?

Tags: expected-value

I have this statement:

> Some game of throw a dice with two equiprobable sides, with the number
>   $1$ and $2$. If you get $1$ You win $200\$$ and if you get $2$ you
>   lose $100\$$, after $100$ launches what value is expected to win?

My attempt was:

I understand that expected value is a theorical concept that give us an averague value of the experiment, something like the average, but with probabilities.

For this exercise i should calculate the expected value, but my doubt are:

i) Is my theorical concept correct?

And more important, to solve this exercise:

ii) The expected value applies by independent to each repetition of the experiment?, i.e when i go to calculate the expected value i should multiplicate the expected value by the number of repetitions?. Per example if i play this game $1$ time i hope to win $50\$$ but if i play this game the $100$ times i should hope The same money as if I played it once?, i.e $50\$$ Or multiplied by the times I will play? in this case 100 times $50\$ \cdot 100 = 5000\$$ ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming each game is independent, then each time you play, you expect to win $1/2\cdot 200 - 1/2\cdot 100 = 50$ dollars. It doesn't matter how many times you play.

Comment: Yes, expected value is linear: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For each roll, the expected outcome is
$$(\textrm{net result for }1) \cdot P(1) + (\textrm{net result for }2) \cdot P(2)$$

You should be able to compute this explicitly.

Since the results for each roll don’t depend on previous results, the expected outcome for $n$ rolls is $n$ times the expected outcome for a single roll.

Comment: So i'll win $5000\$$ ?

Comment: “Will win”? No. But if a large number of people roll 100 times each, the average winnings among all these people will be approximately 5000. No specific outcome is ever guaranteed. The expected value is like a long-term average of repeated experiments. If you roll 100 times, it is possible (but not likely) that you will lose every single time. Just like if you flip a coin 100 times, you *might* get heads every time, but this is not likely.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.